# App deployment failed

Tags: google-app-engine, visual-studio-2017, google-cloud-platform

I am starting to use the App Engine on Google Cloud. I downloaded the sample app from Google and run it and it works fine. When I created a new project in VS2017 in .Net Core Razor Pages. I ran it on my computer with no issues. However, when I went to deploy it to the cloud it fails. I accessed the logs from both. The first log is from the sample app. The second log is my own project. I do not see any errors or anything different in the logs. Am I missing something?

```html
{
 httpRequest: {
  latency:  "0.135s"   
  referer:  "-"   
  remoteIp:  "2607:fcc8:608c:3a00:de8:d13b:5871:2a5"   
  requestMethod:  "GET"   
  requestUrl:  "/"   
  responseSize:  "22"   
  status:  200   
  userAgent:  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"   
 }
 insertId:  "1uvem8cg1szzlpp"  
 jsonPayload: {
  appLatencySeconds:  "0.135"   
  httpRequest: {
   protocol:  "HTTP/1.1"    
  }
  latencySeconds:  "0.135"   
  trace:  "8f73f754de13f45c2a52f96d68fa0aea"   
 }
 labels: {
  appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name:  ""   
  appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id:  "8f73f754de13f45c2a52f96d68fa0aea"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "1319068021706788373"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "b083e85685ef"   
  compute.googleapis.com/zone:  "us-east4-c"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/psa-199021/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-04-04T11:07:35.003592385Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id:  "default"    
   project_id:  "psa-199021"    
   version_id:  "20180404t070131"    
  }
  type:  "gae_app"   
 }
 timestamp:  "2018-04-04T11:07:29.814Z"  
}
```

Second log of project that failed

```html
{
 httpRequest: {
  latency:  "0.003s"   
  referer:  "https://psa-199021.appspot.com/"   
  remoteIp:  "2607:fcc8:608c:3a00:de8:d13b:5871:2a5"   
  requestMethod:  "GET"   
  requestUrl:  "/favicon.ico"   
  responseSize:  "22"   
  status:  200   
  userAgent:  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"   
 }
 insertId:  "1uvem8cg1szzlpq"  
 jsonPayload: {
  appLatencySeconds:  "0.003"   
  httpRequest: {
   protocol:  "HTTP/1.1"    
  }
  latencySeconds:  "0.003"   
  trace:  "1db22573c8896fb23beff41088c79e14"   
 }
 labels: {
  appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name:  ""   
  appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id:  "1db22573c8896fb23beff41088c79e14"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "1319068021706788373"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "b083e85685ef"   
  compute.googleapis.com/zone:  "us-east4-c"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/psa-199021/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-04-04T11:07:35.003592385Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id:  "default"    
   project_id:  "psa-199021"    
   version_id:  "20180404t070131"    
  }
  type:  "gae_app"   
 }
 timestamp:  "2018-04-04T11:07:30.223Z"  
}
```

Comment: I might be able to help, but I'd need a little more info: a) which sample did you downloaded from Google Cloud? b) Are you using Google Cloud Tools For Visual Studio to deploy? Or how are you deploying? c) When you say that deployment fails, how exactly? Error message?

Comment: Yes I am using Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio. There is no error message in visual studio it just says deployment failed. I followed these instructions and downloaded the sample app on the page. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/quickstart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of 10 April 2018 Google Cloud App Engine .Net Core runtime supports .Net Core 2.0.6.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
This problem might be due to a mismatch between the .Net Core version used by te project created with the MS VS 2017 template and the .Net Core version we are currently supporting in App Engine. You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/aspnet-docker/issues/91).

I can offer two temporary solutions:

1. Edit the *.csproj file and change the .Net Core version to 2.0.0, reload the project on VS and deploy. As follows:

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2. Create your projects using the Google Cloud Templates that are available to you once you have installed the [Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.GoogleCloudPlatformExtensionforVisualStudio) which will use the .Net Core versions supported by App Engine. Here:
   [image: Gloogle Cloud Visual Studio Project Template]

Comment: Thank you Amanda for your help. The first solution was successful.